# DropNet (dropbox) check for path, create if null

Tags: error-handling, dropbox-api, dropnet

I can successfully connect to dropbox using the dropnet API. I want to check if a directory (path) exists.  There's got to be a better way than handling it as an error?

```
private void LoadContents()
    {
        string _path = null;
        //_path = "/";
        _path = "/PathDoesNotExist";
        _client.GetMetaDataAsync(_path, (response) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(response.Contents.Count(c => c.Is_Dir) + " Folders found.");
        },
        (error) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to get the metadata of the parent folder and check its contents for the folder. Other than that it would be checking the exception for a Response with a 404.

Comment: I have to say that looking for a 404 seems more efficient to me than listing the entire parent directory. (Also, you still have to deal with the fact that the parent directory might not exist.)